# What is a kview?

Tags: support, design

Every once in a while, "kviews" shows up next to a question in a list of questions, instead of "views".  What is it, why is it, and what's the difference?

Comment: kilo (10^3) views.

Comment: Ah.  Should have guessed that.

Comment: It [happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208056/is-it-just-me-or-did-the-user-profile-layout-just-change-to-a-collapsed-bar) to the best of us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kviews` stands for `kilo-views`, 1000 views.